# SQL Server Date Range Problem When Using Data From Web Server Logs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, iis

I have been importing my raw IIS log files into a SQL Server table using the
Log Parser tool for several months now. This is done to enable the writing of
SSRS reports based on this log data.

One of the reports that I am working on is supposed to determine the number of
Visits from each unique IP address. A Visit is defined as an IP address hitting
a page on the site and then making 4 more requests within an hour of each
other. All of the 5 requests are within one Visit to the site. Later on that
night the same IP address hits the site, except that now it's 3 hours later, so
we count this new activity from the same IP as a new Visit. Here is a sample of
the data:

```
IPAddress,   RequestDateTime,     UriStem
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 13:30:30, /
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 13:30:31, /style.css
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 13:30:31, /script.js
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 13:30:32, /funny.gif
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 13:30:33, /picture.jpg
10.1.1.101,  2010-10-15 13:40:50, /page2.html
10.1.1.101,  2010-10-15 13:40:51, /style.css
10.1.1.102,  2010-10-15 14:10:20, /page4.html
10.1.1.102,  2010-10-15 14:10:21, /style.css
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 16:55:10, /
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 16:55:11, /style.css
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 16:55:11, /script.js
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 16:55:12, /funny.gif
10.1.1.100,  2010-10-15 16:55:13, /picture.jpg
```

By looking at the data above I can easily discern that the `10.1.1.100` IP
address has visited the site twice and had 5 hits on each visit. However, I am
at a loss as to how to express that in SQL code. Is there an easy way to group
and count these date ranges by IP address?

I understand that this information can be captured by using tools such as
AWStats, but I do not have the luxury of being able to install Perl on the
systems we use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the code below a trial run.  The code groups and numbers the visits from each IP address.  Then it looks to see how many "uristem" hits compared with the "threshold" value.  I tested the code on a table named "Foo" and you need to check your table and column names prior to running the test.

```
DECLARE @threshold INT;  
SET @threshold = 4;  --this number should not include the initial visit
DECLARE @lookbackdays int; 
SET @lookbackdays = 300; 

;WITH postCTE as  
(  
SELECT   
    ipaddress,  
    uristem,  
    requestdatetime,  
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ipaddress,requestdatetime ASC)  
FROM  
    Foo  --put your table name here
WHERE  
    requestdatetime > GETDATE() - @lookbackdays 
)  
--select * from postCTE

SELECT   
    p1.ipaddress AS [ipaddress],   
    p2.RowNumber - p1.RowNumber +1 AS [Requests], 
    p1.requestdatetime AS [DateStart]
FROM  
    postCTE p1  
INNER JOIN  
    postCTE p2   
    ON p1.ipaddress = p2.ipaddress   
    AND p1.Rownumber = p2.RowNumber - (@threshold )  
WHERE  
    DATEDIFF(minute,p1.requestdatetime,p2.requestdatetime) <= 60
```

The output of my test on SQL 2008 is

```
ipaddress   Requests    DateStart
10.1.1.100  5   2010-10-15 13:30:30.000
10.1.1.100  5   2010-10-15 16:55:10.000
```

Comment: using partition by ipaddress order by requestdatetime would allow to easier manipulate the results and analyse further

Comment: RC_Cleland: Your approach is interesting and I will try to use it as a starting point for now, but there are a couple of errors with the logic: It always groups in bundles of five requests... In a much expanded data source, I am unable to know ahead of time how many hits from each IP I will have. An IP can have 5 hits or 500 hits in a single visit.

Comment: I used a threshold variable, the number of additional visits, because you had mentioned the number 5 in your question.  One could change the threshold number or even replace it with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to summarize your data first, then generate your report.

Here's how I'd do it.

1. Create a SummaryTable with the FACTS you want (e.g. UserIP, SessionStart, SessionEnd, PageViews)
2. Figure out what you consider a new visit (e.g. I think IIS default session timeout is 20 minutes, so any consecutive hit by an IP after 20 minutes I'll consider a new visit.)
3. Create a cursor to calculate the summarized data based on your rule.

   ```
   -- Summary Data
   DECLARE @UserIP AS VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @SessionStart AS DateTime
   DECLARE @SessionEnd AS DateTime
   DECLARE @PageViews AS INT


   -- Current Values
   DECLARE @ThisUserIP AS VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @ThisVisitTime AS DateTime
   DECLARE @ThisPage AS VARCHAR(100)


   -- Declare Cusrsor
   DECLARE StatCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
   -- Query, make sure you sort by IP/Date so their data is in cronological order
   SELECT IPAddress, RequestDateTime, UriStem
   FROM Stats
   ORDER BY IPAddress, RequestDateTime


   OPEN StatCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM StatCursor
   INTO @ThisUserIP, @ThisVisitTime, @ThisPage


   -- Start New Summary
   SELECT @UserIP = @ThisUserIP, @SessionStart = @ThisVisitTime, @SessionEnd = @ThisVisitTime, @PageViews = 1


   FETCH NEXT FROM StatCursor
   INTO @ThisUserIP, @ThisVisitTime, @ThisPage


   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN


   -- Check rule
   IF @UserIP = @ThisUserIP AND @ThisVisitTime &lt;= DATEADD(MI,30,@SessionEnd)
       BEGIN
           -- Same User and Session / Add to Summary
           SELECT @PageViews = @PageViews + 1, @SessionEnd = @ThisVisitTime
       END
   ELSE
       BEGIN
           -- Different User or New User / Write Current Summary and Start New Summary
           INSERT INTO StatSummary (UserIP, SessionStart, SessionEnd, PageViews) VALUES (@UserIP, @SessionStart, @SessionEnd, @PageViews)
           SELECT @UserIP = @ThisUserIP, @SessionStart = @ThisVisitTime, @SessionEnd = @ThisVisitTime, @PageViews = 1
       END


   FETCH NEXT FROM StatCursor
   INTO @ThisUserIP, @ThisVisitTime, @ThisPage


   END


   CLOSE StatCursor
   DEALLOCATE StatCursor
   ```
4. Create a query to get the data you need, example (All time Hits by IP).

   SELECT UserIP, COUNT(UserIP) FROM StatSummary GROUP BY UserIP

Comment: Zachary: I actually tried the approach with the cursor and it worked really well for really small data sets (in the thousands of rows) but the actual data set that I need to work with is in the billions of rows and this cursor approach is actually processing rows slower than my web servers are creating log entries.

Comment: Wow, that's some serious data... I use AWStats for most of my logging and what it does is generate the summaries for the current day on a daily/hourly basis... so your never waiting to do it all at one time.  Once the raw data is processed, you never have to process or use it again!  Do the reports have to be real-time?  Can you process in batch?  Also, do you have any indexes on your raw data?